# Camel FTPS Component Auto Create Directory

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, ftps

I am using the Camel FTP component (FTPS) to connect to an IBM iSeries and their log is filling up with statements such as:

**Denied for EXPUSER to / LONDON type *IFS. Function CRT_DIR. IP address**

I understand that the denied is because the user does not have the authority to create directories, but how can I stop this happening altogether? Is there an option I can add to stop this happening altogether as I don't need to create directories.

The current **from** route is

```
from(ftps://user@10.140.5.58:990//london/luprocess/to_embargo?password=password
&binary=true&move=.done&siteCommand=NAMEFMT 1&isImplicit=true&passiveMode=true
&timeout=10000&ftpClient.keyStore.file=C:/keys/key.jks
&ftpClient.keyStore.password=password&ftpClient.keyStore.keyPassword=password)
.to(file://C:/messageOut);
```

Comment: Well it is a bit hard to help if we don't know how the camel code looks.

Comment: Added the from camel route to the question now.

Comment: Which directory is it trying to create which is not allowed? From what I can see it seems to be ".done" directory stated in the move parameter. If it is not allowed to create it by the system then you need to change your route and remove that parameter or give it  access.

Comment: The problem is that the **London** and **luprocess** directories have been created on the iSeries but the Camel FTP component is trying to create them and getting an access denied. The reason for this is that it doesn't have the authority to create directories but this is not required as they are already there. Is there a way to remove this so the create directory command does not run?

Comment: Try with stepwise=false

Answer (score 0):

Camel will not create the source polling folder if they already exit.  This is default behavior.  I think the camel user does not have permission to create the directory  .done inside the source folder.  Either that or the path is not correct and hence it tries to create the missing folder.

Edit: 
So this is what the Camel documentation says:

> For Camel versions before Camel 2.16, the directoryName must exist
>   already as this component does not support the autoCreate option
>   (which the file component does). The reason is that its the FTP
>   administrator (FTP server) task to properly setup user accounts, and
>   home directories with the right file permissions etc.
>
> For Camel 2.16, autoCreate option is supported. When consumer starts,
>   before polling is scheduled, there's additional FTP operation
>   performed to create the directory configured for endpoint. The default
>   value for autoCreate is true.

So if you are using a version less than 2.16 it will not create the directory for you. If you are on version 2.16 set autoCreate=false.

By the way, you have a double slash in your path.

```
10.140.5.58:990//london
```

In the documentation is is single slash.

```
10.140.5.58:990/london
```

Comment: The **.done** folder has been created and files are moved into it so that all works fine but the log on the server side shows that a create directory command is trying to run for the **/London** and then the **/luprocess**. This is what I want to remove or at least understand.

Comment: Commented your slash as well.

Comment: I am using a version before 2.16 so it should not be trying to create the directory for me. I expect it should find the directory and complete the command, but this is not the case.

Comment: Did you notice the slash?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I doubt it is this. The function **Function CRT_DIR** that is in the server log sounds like a command is running.